# not able to enable the timeout manager in a distributor with Production profile in a Master node

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4, nservicebus-distributor

After deploying my service as a Master with production profile I don't see the timeout manager to get enabled in the initialiazation. I have tried everything with no success.

The way I install the service is:

> NServiceBus.Host.exe  /install  /serviceName:BusinessServices
>   /displayName:BusinessServices /description:BusinessServices
>   /userName:machinename\Administrator /password:pass
>   NServiceBus.Master nservicebus.production

The endpointconfig is:

> public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint,
>   AsA_Server,AsA_Publisher {
>          }

And the configuration is:

> ```
>  <MasterNodeConfig Node="machinename"/>
>
> <TransportConfig MaximumConcurrencyLevel="50" />
> ```

RavenDB is installed in that machine and works well for saga, anyway in the initialization it says:

> 2014-05-19 17:02:55,428 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Configure [(null)]
>   <(null)> - Invocation of NServiceBus.IWantToRunBeforeConfiguration
>   completed in 0.14 s 2014-05-19 17:02:55,785 [1] INFO 
>   NServiceBus.Configure [(null)] <(null)> - Invocation of
>   NServiceBus.Config.INeedInitialization completed in 0.00 s 2014-05-19
>   17:02:56,296 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Licensing.LicenseManager [(null)]
>   <(null)> - Expires on 07/03/2014 00:00:00 2014-05-19 17:02:56,576 [1]
>   INFO  NServiceBus.Configure [(null)] <(null)> - Invocation of
>   NServiceBus.INeedInitialization completed in 0.79 s 2014-05-19
>   17:02:56,724 [1] INFO 
>   NServiceBus.Distributor.T5.BusinessServices.High [(null)] <(null)> -
>   Endpoint configured to host the distributor, applicative input queue
>   re routed to T5.BusinessServices.High.worker@WIN-74CD8F6BJ66
>   2014-05-19 17:02:57,118 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Configure [(null)]
>   <(null)> - Invocation of
>   NServiceBus.IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized completed in 0.54
>   s 2014-05-19 17:02:57,356 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Features.Sagas
>   [(null)] <(null)> - Sagas found in scanned types, saga persister
>   enabled 2014-05-19 17:02:57,371 [1] INFO 
>   NServiceBus.Features.FeatureInitializer [(null)] <(null)> - Features: 
>   Audit [4.6.1] - Enabled AutoSubscribe [4.6.1] - Enabled
>   BinarySerialization [4.6.1] - Controlled by category Serializers
>   BsonSerialization [4.6.1] - Controlled by category Serializers
>   JsonSerialization [4.6.1] - Controlled by category Serializers
>   XmlSerialization [4.6.1] - Controlled by category Serializers
>   MsmqTransport [4.6.1] - Enabled Gateway [4.6.1] - Enabled
>   TimeoutManager [4.6.1] - Disabled Sagas [4.6.1] - Enabled
>   SecondLevelRetries [4.6.1] - Enabled StorageDrivenPublisher [4.6.1] -
>   Enabled MessageDrivenSubscriptions [4.6.1] - Enabled Heartbeats
>   [1.0.0] - Enabled SagaAudit [1.0.0] - Enabled

Do I have to do anything more?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As Jon said in the comment ... if you are configuring a server as a distributor or master, you don't want the MasterConfig config section. Having that section will disable the timeout manager, as it expects to defer that logic to the configured master.

Comment: If you are configuring a server as a distributor or master, you don't want the MasterConfig config section. Having that section will disable the timeout manager, as it expects to defer that logic to the configured master.

Comment: yes, that's true, and it is cleaner. Updating my answer